# Debundle angular 7 application

Tags: angular, angular7, decompiler

Is there any way to debundle angular 7 application build and get original source files. Right now I have only dist folder and I want original source files.

Comment: No, it isn't possible to derive source code from the bundles.

Comment: i doubt it. you could try something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-unpack but i doubt you will get a positive outcome